# client validation for Ajaxtool CalendarExtender to check end date Range not exceed to 6 month from start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is ASP.Net code:

Controls : Ajax CalendarExtender

Here i used server side validation click event. I need to validate client side for this scenario using Jquery in "OnClientDateSelectionChanged".

```
      Dim str As String
      FromDate = txtFromdate.Text
      ToDate = txtTodate.Text

    str = FromDate.AddMonths(6)
    If (FromDate.AddMonths(6) <= ToDate) Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "showalert", "alert('Enter the Date Range between 6 Months');", True)
    End If
```

can any one give some idea. please

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: The above code is working fine. but i want to validate this from client "Jquery" on calendarExtender "OnClientDateSelectionChanged" event.